# Kid templates, discover all keywords?

Tags: python, templates

I would like to discover all the keywords in a [Kid](http://www.turbogears.org/1.0/docs/GettingStarted/Kid.html) template - that is, everything that needs to be passed to instantiate the template.  Clearly, I could search for `${`, but there are complications with this such as the expression inside the `${}` could be complex.  Also this does not address the xml markup that Kid provides.

Another possibility is to execute the template, catch the `NameError` exception, fill in a "dummy" value and repeat.  This is almost too painful to contemplate! :-)

There must be a better way!

Comment: Perhaps ask on the [mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/kid-template-discuss)? A search reveals only 4 kid template questions here on SO, so I find it unlikely that you'll get an answer here.

Comment: Try passing `s = collections.defaultdict(lambda: None)` as your variables. After the template output is produced, evaluate `s.keys()` to see what keys were looked up in the dictionary.